# Java Jquery drop-down issue

Tags: jquery

I have created a jquery menu using some online resources & i have embedded the jquery in a google ad box already existing in my script. (I didnt have any other space suitable) the problem is the box is not showing all the options & gets hidden within the ad box itself. please have a look at the below link. m talking about the home, english, etc menu. I would really appreciate your help. thanks.

http://www.songspal.com/music/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It's the style rules on `.clsHeaderRight` and `.clsTopHeader, #selNav` causing your problem.  They are set to `overflow:hidden`  You either have to remove those styles (seems to have no ill effects) or take the menu out of flow (not the best idea).

(header.css lines 412 and 383)

Comment: @Joseph... your a saviour :) that worked.. hope I can help ppl the same way some day.. thanks so much........

Comment: @javanewbee Glad to help :) it is indeed a joy to be able help others :)